# How to prompt the user for a block of text in elisp?

Tags: emacs, elisp

`read-from-minibuffer` is a great way to prompt a user for a single line of text.  How do I prompt a user for a large block of multi-line text in elisp?

This is what I'm thinking, but I don't know if it's the smoothest approach:

1. create a temporary buffer (via `with-temporary-buffer`?)
2. seed the buffer with some default text
3. display the buffer
4. tell the user, "edit the text as you see fit, then hit <some key sequence> to indicate that you are done" (perhaps via `header-line-format`)
5. wait for the user to hit the key sequence
6. collect the buffer text and put it in a variable (via `buffer-string`)
7. destroy the temporary buffer and restore the window layout as it was before
8. do stuff with the text

Comment: What do you actually want to do?  I.e. what is your overall goal with the collected "block of text"?

Comment: @event_jr: I want to write some library code that I can reuse in various circumstances

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(defun my-read-mb-lines (prompt some-keyseq)
  (let ((keymap (copy-keymap minibuffer-local-map)))
    (define-key keymap (kbd "RET") 'newline)
    (define-key keymap some-keyseq 'exit-minibuffer)
    (read-from-minibuffer prompt nil keymap)))
```

Calling example:

```
(my-read-mb-lines "Insert text (C-s to submit): " (kbd "C-s"))
```

The 'let' block creates a local copy of the minibuffer's default keymap. The next two calls to "define-key" modify the keymap copy. Afterward, "read-from-minibuffer" passes the modified keymap for the minibuffer to use while prompting the user (instead of its default keymap, "minibuffer-local-map").

FWIW, C-j is mapped to "exit-minibuffer" by default and a simplified version can be written:

```
(defun my-simplified-read-mb-lines (prompt)
  (let ((keymap (copy-keymap minibuffer-local-map)))
    (define-key keymap (kbd "RET") 'newline)
    (read-from-minibuffer prompt nil keymap)))
```

Calling example:

```
(my-simplified-read-mb-lines "Insert text (C-j to submit): ")
```

Comment: Richard - in emacs version 24.2 there's a variable called "resize-mini-windows" that might be set differently for you. The default is 'grow-only but if you set it to true then you might get nicer behavior:
(let ((keymap (copy-keymap minibuffer-local-map))
      (resize-mini-windows t))
etc...

Comment: Playing with the "max-mini-window-height" variable might also get you there but it's relatively new.

Comment: I'm running 23.4.  With `max-mini-window-height` set to 0.25 and `resize-mini-windows` set to `t`, it still shows only one line.  Maybe this was fixed in v24?

Comment: I don't think so - I just tested the above code in a bare session of v23.2 and it worked. It might be one of your customizations/config settings or the way that you're invoking the function. If you startup emacs with the -q flag and evaluate the above code inside the scratch buffer you'll be able to rule out whether your configurations are the cause.

Comment: You're right:  the problem was `(custom-set-variables '(truncate-lines t))`

Comment: This was fixed in Emacs v24 (minibuffers always set `truncate-lines` to `nil`).  For Emacs v23 users, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/1775898/712605

Answer (score 2):

I suppose it depends on the exact use-case?

There are no shortage of examples of your proposed approach working very nicely (e.g. writing a VCS commit message), so there's certainly nothing wrong with that -- it's tried and true. In addition, if it really is a large (or simply not *small*) block of text, then I suspect that providing a normal buffer to edit in may provide the nicest experience for the user.

If you're talking about collecting *multiple* input fields *including* a multi-line field, then the widget-based approach (as suggested by wvxvw) would enable you to put everything in a single buffer, which might also be desirable.

Or you could use the `mail`-like approach of using a single buffer for multiple fields, and then parse the results afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

First of all Emacs 23.4 is very old.  You should upgrade.

The work-flow you describe is what org-mode uses to edit source blocks.
Org-mode is included in Emacs 24.

See the source of `org-edit-special` for how it works.

It does a bit more than you need.

Basically, you want to set up a minor-mode for the created buffer that has a
binding to gather the text and restore window configuration.

I've written [ges](https://github.com/lewang/generic-edit-special) to edit arbitrary blocks in a new buffer using org-mode
machinery, but it's more complex than what you need.

Comment: Can you provide an example of how to use `generic-edit-special`?

Comment: You can follow the installation instructions for HTMl, and hit `C-c '` in any JS or CSS block.